# How to deploy application in google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, authentication, deployment

I am trying to deploy my python application in Google app engine, using its launcher. But it is giving error:

```
Error 404: --- begin server output ---
This application does not exist (app_id=u'testappengine').
--- end server output ---
Your browser has been opened to visit:
```

I cross checked my app.yaml file, but this application is there.Am I missing any step. or is there some other way to deploy in google app engine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before to do the deploy you need to create a new appengine with the name that you want, in this case testappengine, on https://appengine.google.com/start/createapp

:)

Comment: I am using app launcher, so there I was creating application and then deploying it. Do I have to explicitly create an appengine in the provided link, apart from that in launcher??

Comment: Yes! You should to create the appengine apart from the launcher.

Comment: you app will be deployed to appname.appspot.com and you have to reserve  *appname* in advance or you'd be overwriting other peoples apps :)

Answer (score 0):

Go to command prompt..
Change to local directory (mine is C:\Googe Apps Engine\surveypertama)
Use no cookies parameter..

```
C:\Googe Apps Engine\surveypertama>appcfg.py update --no_cookies app.yaml
```

Worked for me